# R Tidyverse: filter over multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

How can I tell R (dplyr) to "reset" the filter, which would allow me to filter a second time within the same pipe? 
Otherwise, I would have to write a "for-loop" for every identifier number.
The minimal working example highlights the problem, that I am facing.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.tibble <- tribble(                      # sample data
  ~id,~year, ~identifier, ~items, ~cost,
  10, 2018, "aaca" , 10, 25, # "aaca" toy cars
  20, 2018, "aaca" , 12, 28, # "aaca" toy cars
  10, 2018, "bbda" , 14, 30, # "bbda" pens 
  20, 2018, "bbda" , 27, 29, # "bbda" pens
)

a <-data.tibble %>%                        # FIRST BLOCK WORKS FINE on its own 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(identifier, "^a")) %>% # lookks for identifier that begins
  summarise(toycars_sold=sum(items),       # with "a" 
            toycars_cost=sum(cost)) 
a 

b <- data.tibble %>%                       # Second block works fine on its own
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(identifier,"^b")) %>% 
  summarise(pens_sold=sum(items),
            pens_cost=sum(cost))
b
```

*I run into trouble, and get an error message if I ask dplyr to filter again for a different identifier within the same pipe*

```
data.tibble %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(identifier, "^a")) %>% 
  summarise(toycars_sold=sum(items),
            toycars_cost=sum(cost)) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(identifier,"^b")) %>% 
  summarise(pens_sold=sum(items),
            pens_cost=sum(cost))


What i would like to end up with is

c <- full_join(a,b)

There are a myriad of codes ("identifiers") that I will have to go through ( sometimes there is more than one identifier for a single item.
```

R then tells me, that the object "identifier" cannot be found.

Any help is highly appreciated.

## old question, which was a little bit hard to understand

i do have a question that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Here is my question, how can I tell tidyverse to reset the filter, after the first summary() function is called. Otherwise, I would have to create a "for-loop" for every "id-code" ( i believe regex is the correct terminology) that I want to filter over.

```
output <- vector("list") # object to store output in 

for (i in seq_along(object18)) { # object (list) to loop over, here items of stores in yr 18 
  output[[i]] <- object18[[i]] %>% 
    group_by(storeid, month, year, quarter) %>%  # var list to group over
    filter(str_detect(itemcode, "^CODE")) %>%   # Code equals some identifiernr ("string")
    summarize(toys=sum(items), # summarize
              max.items.sold=max(items)) # summarize %>%
    filter(str_detect(itemcode, "^NEWCODE, possibly multiple codes) %>% # FILTER OVER NEW CODE DOESN'T WORK
    summarize(toys2=sum(items), # summarize
             (itemstoy2=max(items)) # summarize 
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to reach my goal?

Please don't be to harsh on me, I'm pretty new to R.

Thanks in advance, Davide.

Comment: Perhaps you need `group_by` to work on each itemcode? It would help if you provided sample data (`dput(head(x))` in a code block) and intended output given that sample data.

Comment: +1 to @r2evans comment.  My immediate reaction is that if you're filtering in the middle of a loop down a vector, then your problem is most likely with your data format.  Sample input data and desired output would be very helpful.

Comment: do you know about `%T>%` pipe from magrittr. I do  not have a solution, but I think using  this you may be a step in the direction you want to go... you can read about it a little bit here https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html#

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "roll back" a `filter` and return to the original unfiltered data within a pipe. It might be possible to implement this kind of functionality, however, in the `tidyverse` there are better options to achieve the same output.

For this kind of problems I would:

1. define a custom function, which takes a `data.frame` and your regex filter (as string) as arguments and returns the sums of `sold` and `costs`.
2. Define a named vector with your item names as names and your regex filter as values.
3. Wrap the existing data in a list inside a `tibble` and cross it with the vector from 2 and adding the vector names as new column.
4. Apply the custom function defined in 1. with `map2` to generate a filtered data set.
5. select the (item) names column and the column with your filtered data and unnest.

Now you have your data in the long format. This is already a good format to work with for many tasks. In a last step you can bring it into your desired format by ...

5. ... using `pivot_wider`

In case you want to filter more than just a regex you would need to create a list of expressions (instead of a character vector) and cross your tibble with this filter list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.tibble <- tribble(                      # sample data
  ~id,~year, ~identifier, ~items, ~cost,
  10, 2018, "aaca" , 10, 25, # "aaca" toy cars
  20, 2018, "aaca" , 12, 28, # "aaca" toy cars
  10, 2018, "bbda" , 14, 30, # "bbda" pens 
  20, 2018, "bbda" , 27, 29, # "bbda" pens
)

sum_filter <- function(.df, .filter) {

  .df %>% 
    group_by(id, year) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(identifier, .filter)) %>%
    transmute(sold = sum(items),
              cost = sum(cost))

}

filter_vec <- c("toycars" = "^a",
                "pens" = "^b")

tibble(data = list(data.tibble)) %>%
  crossing(filters = filter_vec) %>% 
  mutate(name = names(filter_vec),
         filtered_data = map2(data, filters, sum_filter)) %>% 
  select(name, filtered_data) %>% 
  unnest(cols = filtered_data) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = c(sold, cost))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>      id  year sold_toycars sold_pens cost_toycars cost_pens
#>   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1    10  2018           10        14           25        30
#> 2    20  2018           12        27           28        29
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>